# PHP code for Current Date filter with Mysql

Tags: php, sql

I have a table with numerous colums the SQL query I want to draw information from that table and just show information for the current month up to the current date

This is what I currently have

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM lbs_trace_etrack WHERE lbs_client='$slcustom1' AND WHERE 
 MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(lbs_date, '%Y/%m/%d')) = MONTH(NOW()) "
```

It is not showing any records for this month at all

Thank you for assistance

Comment: How is the format of the values ​​in `lbs_date` field?

Comment: 2013-12-01 it is DATE type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is wrong, had two WHEREs words, correct for:

```
$query = "
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        lbs_trace_etrack 
    WHERE 
        lbs_client = '".$slcustom1."'
    AND MONTH (lbs_date) = MONTH (NOW())";
```

Ever enable errors on PHP to see errors:

```
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", true);
```

Comment: If I want to do the same for the current day do I just change MONTH to DAY?

Comment: Yes, simple, is not it?